# How can I include a function in the Standard Deviation parameter of pnorm

Tags: r

I want to create a function a(v,x) using pnorm but with the standard deviation of pnorm that depends on x. R returns the error : non-numeric argument to mathematical function.

I am quite new to R so I don't really know how to handle the problem but i did not manage to find any answer elsewhere.

```r
x0 = 6
R = 5 
r = 2
p=0.5
sig = 5
sigR <- function(x){ sig*(x - r)*sqrt(p*(1-p))}

a <- function(v,x) {
 pnorm(v + p*(x0-x) + (1-p)*(R-r), sd = sigR)
  }
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

Since `sigR` is a function of `x`, you need to pass the `x` value to that function to get a constant out. The `sd=` parameter expects a numeric value, not a function.

```
a <- function(v,x) {
 pnorm(v + p*(x0-x) + (1-p)*(R-r), sd = sigR(x))
}
```